# I want to be able to chose which nodes to be printed when importing an XML document to Python

Tags: python, xml, nodes

I am using python to display information from a XML file hosted on a website. The code I am using is bellow:

```
#IMPORTS
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib

#IMPORTING XML FILE
xmldocurl = 'http://gamebattles.majorleaguegaming.com/ps4/call-of-duty-ghosts/team/TeamCrYpToNGamingEU/stats.xml'
settings = urllib.urlopen(xmldocurl).read()
final = minidom.parseString(settings)

date = final.getElementsByTagName('date')


for node in date:
    test = node.getAttribute('timestamp')
    print test
```

This returns the following:

```
1411853400
1411850700
1411847100
1411843500
1411839000
1411837200
1411831800
1411828200
1411822800
1411820100
```

I only want it to return the timestamp for the first node under the heading recent matches. This code at the moment returns everything called timestamp but I only want a specific one.

How can I choose this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the recentMatches object and look at the `date` of the first match. One way to do that is:

```
#IMPORTS
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib

#IMPORTING XML FILE
xmldocurl = 'http://gamebattles.majorleaguegaming.com/ps4/call-of-duty-ghosts/team/TeamCrYpToNGamingEU/stats.xml'
settings = urllib.urlopen(xmldocurl).read()
final = minidom.parseString(settings)

recentMatches = final.getElementsByTagName('recentMatches')[0]

for node in recentMatches.childNodes:
    if node.nodeName == "match":
        nodes = node.getElementsByTagName('url')
        print nodes[0].childNodes[0].data
        nodes = node.getElementsByTagName('date')
        print nodes[0].getAttribute('timestamp')
        break
```

This will iterate over the matches and get you the first date timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I wanted to instead find the first URL under recent matches instead of the first time stamp how could this be done?

Comment: You'd basically do the same code but then for the `url` element instead of the `date` element.

Comment: I did:

`recentMatches = final.getElementsByTagName('recentMatches')

for match in recentMatches:
    date_node = match.getElementsByTagName('match')
    timestamp = date_node[0].getAttribute('url')
    print timestamp
    break`

and got returned an empty space.

Do you know why this is?

Thanks

Comment: @crossboy007 I have updated the code, it's been a while since I wrote XMl. Basically you're iterating over the matches and when you have a match node, you access the `url` and `date` elements (of which there should be one each).